# How do fetch the state with custome query? Corda application using Spring boot webserver- error while fetching the result

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, corda

I have created the IOU in corda applicatiion, the IOU has ID,xml payload in body, partyName. NOW, i want to fetch the state with custome query that is basis on ID. NOTE- i am not using linearID.

Below is my API call- which gives me syntax error on. Can someone please correct me, what is the wrong thing that i am doing.

```
@GetMapping(value = ["getIous"],produces = [ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE])
    private fun getTransactionOne(@RequestParam(value = "payloadId") payloadId: String): ResponseEntity<List<IOUState>> {
        val generalCriteria = QueryCriteria.VaultQueryCriteria(Vault.StateStatus.ALL)
        val results = builder { IOUState::iouId.equal(payloadId)
            val customCriteria = QueryCriteria.VaultCustomQueryCriteria(results)}

            val criteria = customCriteria.and(customCriteria)

            val res = proxy.vaultQueryBy<IOUState>(criteria)
            return ResponseEntity.ok(res)
    }
```

Comment: which line you getting syntax error ?

Comment: Line1- val customCriteria = QueryCriteria.VaultCustomQueryCriteria(results)} Line2- val criteria = customCriteria.and(customCriteria), Line3- return ResponseEntity.ok(res)

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is because `VaultCustomQueryCriteria` is applicable only to `StatePersistable` objects. So you should use `PersistentIOU` instead of `IOUState`. Also, I could see incorrect use of brackets. Here is how your code should look like:

```
@GetMapping(value = ["getIous"],produces = [ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE])
private fun getTransactionOne(@RequestParam(value = "payloadId") payloadId: String): ResponseEntity<List<IOUState>> {
        val generalCriteria = QueryCriteria.VaultQueryCriteria(Vault.StateStatus.ALL)
        val results = builder {
            val idx = IOUSchemaV1.PersistentIOU::iouId.equal(payloadId);
            val customCriteria = QueryCriteria.VaultCustomQueryCriteria(idx)
            val criteria = generalCriteria.and(customCriteria)
            proxy.vaultQueryBy<IOUState>(criteria);
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok(results)
}
```